# htaccess server domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have some simple redirects in my htaccess file. However, the domain is going to change...I was hoping I could write something that gets the domain name?

Someone suggested:

```
 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: can you be more specific about your question?

Comment: If your redirect is local (within the domain), you can leave out the `http://domainname/` part entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the old domain and redirect all the requests to the new one, may this instruction be helpful:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Put the code above in a `.htaccess` file at the root of `old-domain`.

But if you are NOT worried about the old url addresses or search engines crawled your old pages, you won't need to do that, just move all your data (including `.htaccess` file) to your new domain